# Why does the 'vi' command open 'vim' editor?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, vim, vi

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Not that I am complaining as I like my `vim` and prefer its many features. However, I’m curious as to why it does it. It is not aliased in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile.` I am not sure where it gets this behaviour from. Could someone please explain? And also, out of curiosity, is it possible to fire up classic `vi`?

Comment: On many systems vi is a symlink to vim. (If it is a symlink you probably can not open classic vi)

Comment: ... to check that: type `ls  -l /usr/bin/vi` tis will give you ` /usr/bin/vi -> /etc/alternatives/vi` then type `ls -l /etc/alternatives/vi` you will get `/etc/alternatives/vi -> /usr/bin/vim.basic`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because Vim is a well-maintained, vi-compatible, Open Source editor, so it is a perfect match for Linux. I've last seen implementations of pure "vi" on proprietary Unixes like SunOS, HP-UX, AIX; you might get "lucky" on BSD, too. (But of course Vim can be installed on those, too.)

On Ubuntu, what gets installed by default is a stripped-down version of Vim (*vim-tiny*); enough to do vi-style editing. Real Vim users usually install the *vim-gnome* package for a full installation, including the graphical GVIM.

Comment: Note: Arch comes with the original vi by default.

Answer (score 7):

`vim` is the sucessor to `vi`. It stands for vi improved.

`/usr/bin/vi` is just a symlink to vim. You can see this with:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/vi
```

To start "classic vi":

```
vim -u NONE myText.txt
```

How it works: vim looks for a config file at `~/.vimrc`, if this is found it will run as vim unless the line `set compatible` appears in .vimrc. To save editing the .vimrc and adding that line, we tell vim not to bother looking for .vimrc with the `-u NONE` option.

Instead of the `NONE` you could specify a different handwritten config file more suited to setting up vi (vim's .vimrc often confuses vi as it can contain modern vim-specific additions.)

As to why vi is a symlink to vim I've only heard people's opinons. Some say it was to enable running of old scripts. But I don't think I've seen vi or vim invoked in a script much. Others say it was for programmers hardwired to type vi when they want to edit.

Comment: `vim` checks argv[0].  If that is `vi`, it runs in compatibility mode.  See also `sendmail` and `mailq` and similar programs where functionality of the program can be switched by calling it a different name.

Comment: Running vim version 8.0 adding `set compatiblity` produces a error the next time vim is started. The option seems to be `set compatible` instead. Thus changed the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Debian and Ubuntu use a system where symlinks are used to point to alternatives. This is managed using `update-alternatives`. (`man 8 update-altnernatives`)

You'll find `/usr/bin/vi` is symlinked to `/etc/alternatives/vi` and that is symlinked to something like `/usr/bin/vim.gnome`.

The following command will show you which binaries you have installed that provide vi functionality:

```
sudo update-alternatives --list vi
```

This will let you pick a vi binary interactively:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config vi
```

This will let you pick one manually, for example:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set vi /usr/bin/nvi
```

This will let you revert to automatic settings:

```
sudo update-alternatives --auto vi
```

Like others have said, vim can run in vi compatibility mode, but there's a pretty basic vi clone called nvi that you can install as well.

```
sudo apt-get install nvi
```